# How to notify users when the application is closed ( Background Services in Xamarin forms )

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, alarmmanager, signalr-hub, android-workmanager

I am developing an example app based on notifications , with concepts (websockets SignalR ).
all working fine , but when applications are closed users doesn't receive notifications.
i created a service background and recviedbrodcast
MainActivity :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(BackgroundServiceAndroid));
StartService(intent );
}
```

BackgroundServiceAndroid:

```
[Service]
    public class BackgroundServiceAndroid: Service
    {
        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }

        private async void StartWebSocketService()
        {
            await HubClientService.StartWebSocketService();// HubConnectionBuilder ,hubConnection.StartAsync and hubConnection.On<string>("groupName",()) etc.. (working fine , the join group and subscribe ) all users recieve notifications when the app is open
        }  

 public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            StartWebSocketService();
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
```

BroadcastReceiver :

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class ReceiveBoot : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            /* if ((intent.Action != null) &&
                 (intent.Action ==
                     Intent.ActionBootCompleted))
             {
                 Intent start = new Intent(context, typeof(BackgroundReceiver));
                 context.StartService(start);
             }*/



            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "BackgroundReceiver");
            wakeLock.Acquire();
            wakeLock.Release();

        }
```

If my application is running, the notifications appear , else if the app is closed nothing happen.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you should take a look at WorkerManager: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

For iOS, we handle that in the `AppDelegate.PerformFetch()` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiapplicationdelegate.performfetch?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12

To trigger this method you need to add the following line in your `AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching()` method:

```cs
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplication.BackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum);
```